# In a php form, on server side validation failure, need to retrieve the entered form data for displaying

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I have two forms where the data from the first is being sent to the second.

Before the first form data is sent to the second form it is validated on the server.

The first form data consists of a lot of information, so on validation failure, the user needs to enter all the data back again because of a small mistake.

So, is there any solution to pre-fill the form with data on validation failure, so that it makes user comfortable to just fill in the missing data?

Im using PHP with MySQL in ZEND framework and MVC architecture, but I am unable to use Zend_Form.

Comment: If you are using the standard `Zend_Form` setup, then calling `$form->isValid($_POST)` should populate the form with the posted data. If there are errors, then those, too are in the form, renderable via decorators. When the form is rendered in the view, both the errors and the submitted values should be in there (subject to the correct decorators being applied). Is that not what you are seeing? Or is your question related to a validation failure on the _second_ form and the need for the first-form data to be retained?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// your input will validate in the php in your own code then....
$good = 1;
foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
$$k = $v; // this will create variables for your submitted names to post back
if($$k==''){$$k = "needs an entry";$good=0;}
}

if(!$good){
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<input type=text name=demofieldname value='<?php echo $demofieldname ?>'>
- etc- 
</form>


<?php
}else{

//finish processing
}
?>
```

this is a simple method. there are other ways that may be more integrative with your exisiting code and depending on your session management, well, if you are continuing a purchase basket arrangement as in a wizard fashion etc, things can get more complex.

bear in mind - this is simple here and if you have db use then it can be more complicated regarding related queries.

===EDIT NOTE
changed  if($k=='') to  if($$k=='')

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Zend_Form class all data should automatically populated after post request with failures in form. Below example code:

```
$form = new CLASS_EXTENDING_ZEND_FORM;

if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
    }
}

$this->view->form = $form;
```

Comment: sorry but im not using the zend form. the basic html forms

Comment: So if you use Zend Framework I strongly advise to use also Zend Form :)

Comment: hmmm but dats not possible for me now...is der any alternative solution for the phtml forms???

Comment: All fields from html form is available in global variable $_POST (after POST request), so you can check if specified variable is set in $_POST and then set value of form's input.